# Assign integral value to list of relative values

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

I have an assortment of syrups, each of which has a value - the amount of sugar per volume. As people blend these syrups, I track which ones are used, and created a table to get a Relative Weight of each blend. I understand > Data > Sort > Options > Custom Sort Order.

However, I really don't wish to sort each table, and am looking for a way to parse a column of this list as entered, and return a column with results in an Integral Relative Value of each row, as compared to the weights of syrups in the other rows of the table.

```
Unique Name   weight Not Unique  Relative Value
blueberry       .250                       2
raspberry       .333                       3
orange          .425                       4
tangerine       .333                       3
blackberry      .225                       1
```

I am attempting to find the "Relative Sort", a nested function which can assign an integral value of the Unique Name which compares the weights of the syrups. A "Lookup" only works if there is an absolute equality, right?

What if someone doesn't use "blackberry syrup", then "blueberry" is the lightest, and should be labeled as `1`.

Is this too complicated for LibreOffice Calc?

It's a recursive greater than/less than/equal to comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the problem is calculating the right hand column below from entries that may be sorted ascending by value as on the left:

[image]

then an answer is, in C2 and copied down to suit (provided C1 is blank or `0`):

```
=IF(B1<>B2,C1+1,C1)
```

Without sorting the RANK function might be simpler and adequate (though in the example returning `5` rather than `4`).